# Search query> Populate Dropdown field

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, auto-update

I had a search field for searching some client list from database. I had implemented auto complete in that search. Now i need to remove this auto complete and replace it with one drop down box. when i pass a search query in search field; the result should automatically updated in drop down box. Just as auto complete doing. But the difference is, updated content is displaying in another drop down box.

May be this will be a simple job for developers, **but basically i am a designer**. So if there is any custom modules from java script library- "**prototype**" is there then it will be very helpful form me to implement.Actually i had searched for something in prototype library, but can't able to catch one. Otherwise help me to implement this functionality in your views.

Comment: this is confusing. what is result, content, first drop box, another drop box? can you provide more details or a link to a picture?

Comment: ya i had a screenshot. but unfortunately as i am a new user in stack, they didn't allow me to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scriptaculous, which is written on top of prototype, it has an [autocompleter](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/) function